How to display y or x axis break with pgfplots?
Looking at this topic (Axis break in pgfplots), I found a way to "break" my x axis on some data I have. However, I am not truly satisfied with the result. Here is a minimal plot of my simplified problem:
\documentclass{minimal}  
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=7cm,compat=1.18}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{groupplot}[
    group style={group size = 2 by 1,
        horizontal sep=0pt,
        yticklabels at=edge left},
    height=6cm,
    width=4cm,
    ]
    
    \nextgroupplot[
    xmin=0,
    xmax=1.5,
    ymin=0,
    ymax=3.5,
    xtick={0.5},
    axis y line*=left,
    ]
    \addplot coordinates{(1,0)(1,1)(1,2)(1,3)(2,3)(3,3)(4,3)};
    
    \nextgroupplot[
    xmin=3.5,
    xmax=4,
    xtick={3.5,4},
    ymin=0,
    ymax=3.5,
    axis y line*=right,
    axis x discontinuity=parallel
    ]
    \addplot coordinates{(1,0)(1,1)(1,2)(1,3)(2,3)(3,3)(4,3)};  
 \end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

Indeed, here, i am using the command axix x discontinuity but it doesn't "cut" my data at the correct place. I found out that this command puts the parallel symbol at the begining of the groupplots I am working in.
So, is there a way to setup the place where this symbol appears AND to mask the data corresponding to the discontinuity on the graph ?
Here is a concrete example of what kind of graph I would like to be able to do.


Perhaps you could add an image illustrating what you're looking for.

Maybe you could ask on the pgfplots repository.

\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{groupplot}[
group style={group size = 2 by 1, horizontal sep=4pt, yticklabels at=edge left},
width=4cm, height=6cm,
]
\nextgroupplot[
xmin=0, xmax=1.5,
ymin=0, ymax=3.5,
xtick={0.5},
axis y line*=left,
]
\addplot coordinates{(1,0)(1,1)(1,2)(1,3)(2,3)(3,3)(4,3)};

\nextgroupplot[
xmin=3.5, xmax=4,
ymin=0, ymax=3.5,
xtick={3.5,4},
axis y line*=right,
x axis line style={
  insert path={decorate[decoration={ticks, segment length=4pt, amplitude=8pt}]{(current axis.south west) -- +(-5pt,0)}},
  insert path={decorate[decoration={ticks, segment length=4pt, amplitude=8pt}]{(current axis.north west) -- +(-5pt,0)}},
},
]
\addplot coordinates{(1,0)(1,1)(1,2)(1,3)(2,3)(3,3)(4,3)};  
\end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


